# How to say concisely that something solves a big problem for a small group of people?

Tags: phrase-request

I have a blog post that talks about products and services that solve a big problem for a small group of people. I mean, products that specialize in a segment and solve a problem that is very important for them. I am looking for a way to suggest that idea and express it in a short way.

Is it correct to say "help a lot to a few" or "to help very much to a few people"?

Is "help a lot to a few" correct? I know that is not a complete phrase. I want to be something short for a graphic. So I am looking for a suggestion more than an explanation. Is it correct in that context?

Comment: [Niche marketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niche_market)?

Comment: These products and services could be said to have "cornered a niche", especially if they are the only one doing a particular thing (although this does usually mean that most/all people in the niche use said product or service).

Comment: Or perhaps "big impact, small reach" (I don't think this is an idiom, I just made it up).

Comment: I like "big impact, small reach". But, is "help a lot to a few" correct?. (I am not native English and I am learning)

Comment: I like SteveES's suggestion. Meanwhile, another could be, "Helpful even for the little guy" and then your ad would have a picture like [this one](http://www.theagedp.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/LittleGuy-4in.jpg). We use "little guy" in English to indicate that this guy may not be famous or well-known, but he still matters. It's basically flattery :D.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I think "little guy" is a good phrase to know, but "little guy" doesn't really mean "few people" or a niche market. I might make something for big corporations in a very specialized market. There wouldn't be very many of those companies, but they aren't "little guys". I could make something that helps small business owners no matter what kind of business they are in. I am helping the "little guys", but there could be a lot of them.

Comment: There are no small problems.

Comment: @ColleenV, yes, that's true. But I think that the OP had wanted to focus more on the aspect of "a small group of people"? Even the OP's own proposals had been about how to emphasize how the products and services could help either "a lot" or "a few."

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang "LIttle guys" are not a small group of people. They are a class or category of "small" people/companies (in the sense of how much business they do or how much influence they have). See this answer on EL&U for an in-depth explanation: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/122681/

Comment: Yes, @ColleenV, that's the point. Anyway, at this point, I think we're just mincing words. But if you're interested, you can see one such example here that uses "the little guys" precisely to mean "[those of us in smaller markets](https://goo.gl/caf5Au)" (their words, not mine). A simple Google search of "[little guys advertising](https://goo.gl/x0I3Kc)" (per the OP's request of a phrase for a graphic) will show companies that specialize in solving various solutions for small businesses whom they refer to as the little guys.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang OK, you aren't understanding what I said in my first comment. A product that helps 100,000 small businesses is "for the little guys" but doesn't help "a few people". The size of the business isn't the same as the number of people.

Comment: @ColleenV, I hadn't said that it had meant "a few people" until you had said that. I had only said, "the little guy" was someone who "may not be famous or well-known, but he still matters."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, *help a lot to a few* isn't clearly worded. It's likely that English speakers will be vaguely uncomfortable with it since [their brain will start to process it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) as a badly-ordered range (*a lot to a little*) before hitting the ungrammatical *few* and going back to reread and make sense of it. It works technically and maybe poetically, but is somewhat offputting as marketing.

If you are leaving off the subject à la Chinese, you should be aware that it works differently in English. Outside of text messaging, dropped subjects are almost always implicitly *you*: You're giving your customers a command that *they* should go out and help a few a lot.

So

> **We help a few a lot**

is much more cleanly phrased. *We help our few a lot* is more personal. It's still odd that you want to draw attention to the small size of your customer base and their consequent strong negotiating power. It's probably more helpful to just leave it off (*FOO: The experts in BAR*; *BAR Solutions*; *The best in the BAR*; &c.) and muse over the contrast to yourself.